# Can I use switch case in action file in Redux?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redux

I want to use role-based authentication for my react app. I'm using redux and I was thinking that may I check role in action file(as I said I'm using redux).
I have a role_id attribute for my admin that will be 1 for main-admin and 2 for sub-admin. I'm checking this in login function in user.action.js now, it's not going to my dashboard but give me success_login([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9IQF.jpg)) when I'm inspecting my code(but still I'm remaining in login page). I have 2 routes in App.js: '/home' and '/homeAdmin'

I have delete, update and create admin components for main-admin and I don't want to show those to sub-admin.

What is the best approach to do this?
Thanks in advance for the help

This is my login function in user.action.js:

```
function login(email, password) {
return dispatch => {
    dispatch(request({ email }));

    userService.login(email, password)
        .then(
            user => { 
                dispatch(success(user));
                switch(user.role_id) {
                    case 1: return history.push('/home');
                    case 2: return history.push('/homeAdmin');
                    // default: return history.push('/home');
                }
                // history.push('/home');
            },
            error => { 
                dispatch(failure(error));
                dispatch(alertActions.error(error));
            }
        );
};

function request(user) { return { type: userConstants.LOGIN_REQUEST, user } }
function success(user) { return { type: userConstants.LOGIN_SUCCESS, user } }
function failure(error) { return { type: userConstants.LOGIN_FAILURE, error } }
```

}

This one is my in App.js for routing:

```
<PrivateRoute exact path="/home" component={HomePage} /><PrivateRoute exact path="/homeAdmin" component={HomePageSubAdmin}/>
```

Comment: I guess the best approach would be to separate the pushing of new pages and the login process itself. The route change is a side effect of the user logging in. You can move that logic in a separate function and test it separately. Also you can look into `redux-saga` which is a very good way of managing side-effects and test them too.

Comment: thanks but I couldn't get the point ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach is legitimate. Don't listen to people recommending saga just for for **this**.

To separate the redirect target from the login logic, maybe place this in a simple mapping outside of the action creator:

```
const routeForRole = {
    1: '/home',
    2: '/homeAdmin',
    default: '/home'.
};
```

Then the push is a bit more straight forward:

```
history.push(routeForRole[user.role_id] || routeForRole.default);
```

Answer (score 0):

After several trials and failed finally I found that these changes(in user.action.js) are working for me, I'll be happy to hear your ideas, I want to make sure this is a good approach

```
function login(email, password) {
return dispatch => {
    dispatch(request({ email }));

    userService.login(email, password)
        .then(
            user => { 
                dispatch(success(user));

                if ((JSON.stringify(user)).search('"role_id":1')>0) 
                    history.push('/home');
                if ((JSON.stringify(user)).search('"role_id":2')>0) 
                    history.push('/homeAdmin');

                // history.push('/home');
            },
            error => { 
                dispatch(failure(error));
                dispatch(alertActions.error(error));
            }
        );
};

function request(user) { return { type: userConstants.LOGIN_REQUEST, user } }
function success(user) { return { type: userConstants.LOGIN_SUCCESS, user } }
function failure(error) { return { type: userConstants.LOGIN_FAILURE, error } }
```

}

Comment: I would advise against that. Potential vulnerability if the user object contains strings that can be entered by the user, like `"username":"role_id\":1"`. Sanitizing input might prevent this at this point but it's on shaky ground nonetheless. You should look for the property `role_id` instead of searching for the string representation. Was there something that didn't work with the `routeForRole` approach?

Comment: @timotgl Yes, It's not logical to do this. It was a temporary solution that I found. As I choose your solution as an answer I'm using **routeForRole**, Thank you

Answer (score -1):

If you want to be aligned with Redux design it will be good within Action on dispatch of "success" to pass the role id and then Reducer to modify the state property by setting corresponding route based on the role ID either "home" or "homeAdmin" .

You can have dedicated auth component e.g. :

```
 <Route path="/auth" component={Authorize}/>
```

and that just do history.push to whatever is set in state on success or failure.

Here is very nice article to follow for more sophisticated authorization: [link](https://hackernoon.com/role-based-authorization-in-react-c70bb7641db4)

Comment: Thank you, Yes it should work, but because I didn't want to add more component I try that one,

Comment: Sure, It worth considering it because will be better suited for adding unit testing later. Cheers!

Comment: Sorry for keep commenting :) Please consider the error and async handling from UX perspective. If you need to set loading indicator until request is going on you will need to set state in redux also in case of error there will be a need of error message as user feedback and keep user on same page. Sometimes the quick solution might be not the right one in long term. As summary it is not good idea to redirect from Redux action. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank for your time, yes my solution is not the correct one. I'm doing something against the logic work in Redux action.

Comment: @MiroslavSavovski It's perfectly fine to redirect from a redux action, because the reason for the redirect isn't always known/visible to the UI component. Case in point, the original question here. Redirecting to a home route depending on user privileges is not the job of the view layer. Also, what exactly is the purpose of a `Authorize` component? Is it showing a login form? Call it LoginPage, LoginForm, whatever. Is it parsing the user privileges? Then it shouldn't be a component at all. This is not redux design, you're using the component as a crutch to do what the controllers in MVC did.

Comment: @timotgl  . I would refer : https://redux.js.org/introduction/three-principles . Why at all Redux is used in this case? .  I am not against your solution it answers exactly the question but don't understand why you find my unappropriate